# Where can I read a rule about "to be that of" construction?

Tags: grammar

I found this sentence in a book:

> The fundamental problem of communication **is that of** reproducing at one point either exactly or approximately a message selected at another point.

But, what does it mean to use "is that of"?
Why don't we just use "is" ?

Answer (score 1):

If you look into meanings of **that** (and there're many) in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/that), one of the meanings is:

> : the one : the kind
>
> The richest ore is **that** found higher up.

In this example, there's only one richest **ore**, and the phrase following **that** explains where it can be found.

Similarly, in your sentence:

> The fundamental problem of communication is **that** of reproducing at one point either exactly or approximately a message selected at another point.

There's only **one kind** of problem (**The fundamental problem**) and **that** is used to refer to it.